# Use MongoDB with docker-compose: create database and user

Tags: docker, pymongo

Is possible to create a database using docker-compose? I'm trying to run mongodb on docker but I'm not able to create user and initial database :(

```
version: '3.1'

services:
  mongo:
    image: mongo
    restart: always
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE=test
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=admin
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=admin
    volumes:    
      - ~/docker/volumes/mongodb:/data/db
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
```

What is missing in my script?

test code:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

mongo_client = MongoClient('mongodb://%s:%s@127.0.0.1' % ('admin', 'admin'))
cursor = mongo_client.list_databases()
for db in cursor:
    print(db)
```

Answer (score 3):

The above docker-compose seems fine, it will create a user named `admin` and the DB named will be `test` if your `*.js` file contain insert data script. otherwise, it will not create Database because **so if you do not insert data with your JavaScript files, then no database is created**.

You can log in with these credential that specifies in env.

```
  - MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE=test
  - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=test
  - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=admin
```

To initialize DB, you need to mount you DB init script.

```
    volumes:    
      - ~/docker/volumes/mongodb:/data/db
      - youdbscript/init.js:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

**MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE**

> This variable allows you to specify the name of a database to be used
>   for creation scripts in `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/*.js` (see
>   Initializing a fresh instance below). MongoDB is fundamentally
>   designed for "create on first use", **so if you do not insert data with
>   your JavaScript files, then no database is created**.

**Initializing a fresh instance**

> When a container is started for the first time it will execute files
>   with extensions `.sh` and `.js` that are found in
>   `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d`. Files will be executed in alphabetical
>   order. .js files will be executed by mongo using the database
>   specified by the `MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE` variable, if it is present, or
>   test otherwise. You may also switch databases within the `.js` script.

[mongo-docker](https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo)

**Update:**

For your information the code you pasted code is not js file. its python script. Also, change the user name from admin might conflict with admin.

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

mongo_client = MongoClient('mongodb://%s:%s@127.0.0.1' % ('admin', 'admin'))
cursor = mongo_client.list_databases()
for db in cursor:
    print(db)
```

You init script will some thing like

`youdbscript/init.js`

You can try this.

```
db = db.getSiblingDB("test");
db.article.drop();

db.article.save( {
    title : "this is my title" , 
    author : "bob" , 
    posted : new Date(1079895594000) , 
    pageViews : 5 , 
    tags : [ "fun" , "good" , "fun" ] ,
    comments : [ 
        { author :"joe" , text : "this is cool" } , 
        { author :"sam" , text : "this is bad" } 
    ],
    other : { foo : 5 }
});
```

[image]

Comment: Should I add some `.js` file?

Answer (score 0):

Just like @Adiii answer. If you just declare a db name and not insert some data. The db will not created actually.

As your question. You can add one simple script (such as .sh or .js script) to the path `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d`. Like the docs on [mongo](https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo) `Initializing a fresh instance` section.

Comment: I can't even connect using Robo 3T. User `admin/admin` is not being created too.

Comment: Still not working. Geez...a pain to deploy a simple damn container

Comment: Not feel depressed.  can you show me the error info?

Comment: Dont have an error. When I try to connect to db `admin` using credentials `admin/admin`, I got an authorization error on Robo 3T

Comment: First. the test code you parsed run normally？Have you see the docker container  use the `docker ps` command?  Have you rebuild the container?
I have use you code to do. Anything is correct ! also the robo 3t. 
Just try to rebuild more times.

Comment: docker ps shows my container...what do you mean by rebuild container?

Comment: OK. As I begin said.  First add `command: mongod` into end of the `docker-compose.yml`. Then you should rebuild the container to let modify effect. 
Just use the command `docker-compose up --build -d`.

Comment: Authentication failed for db admin, user admin and password admin. I've added command into yml file.

Comment: Maybe you can remove all the previous file and container.  And to begin run from first step? I have confirm twice. but anything is normally...