# MongooseModule: Unable to connect to the database. On a dockerized Nestjs app with Mongo

Tags: mongodb, docker, mongoose, docker-compose, nestjs

I'm trying to start a react-nestjs-mongo db application with docker-compose but for some reason it doesnt seems to work. `docker-compose --build` output shows something like this:

> server     | [Nest] 32   - 06/06/2021, 3:10:25 AM   [MongooseModule] Unable to connect to the database. Retrying (7)... +33006ms
>
> database   | {"t":{"$date":"2021-06-06T03:10:27.406+00:00"},"s":"I",
> "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,
> "ctx":"WTCheckpointThread","msg":"WiredTiger
> message","attr":{"message":"[1622949027:406819][1:0x7f9ae2c3b700],
> WT_SESSION.checkpoint: [WT_VERB_CHECKPOINT_PROGRESS] saving checkpoint
> snapshot min: 7, snapshot max: 7 snapshot count: 0, oldest timestamp:
> (0, 0) , meta checkpoint timestamp: (0, 0)"}}

Here's my docker-compose:

```
version: "3.5"

services:   client:
    container_name: client
    build: ./client
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    depends_on:
      - server

  server:
    container_name: server
    build: ./server
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
    links:
      - mongodb

  mongodb:
    container_name: database
    image: mongo
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: example
```

And my app.modules.ts file looks like this:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { MongooseModule } from '@nestjs/mongoose';

@Module({   
imports: [
    MongooseModule.forRoot('mongodb://localhost:27017/nestjs', {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
    }),   
],   
controllers: [AppController],   
providers: [AppService],
 })  
class AppModule {}
```

Can someone explain me why this isn't working?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are using docker-compose . Thus you are not connecting 'localhost' but it should be address of your 'service' you defined in docker-compose file.

instead of 'mongodb://localhost:27017/nestjs' , you should use (in your case service name you defined in docker-compose is mongodb . You should use 'mongodb://mongodb:27017/nestjs'

Comment: this solved this issue!

Answer (score 3):

I just faced the same issue!

In order to solve it you need to:

- use container name instead of localhost (as manish also suggests)
- provide username and password before host and port as explained in mongose doc: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html
- inialize the database as explained in this question: [Use MongoDB with docker-compose: create database and user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57666606/use-mongodb-with-docker-compose-create-database-and-user)